# struts 2: ajax call to action: one success, one not found in same jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

This is my ajax calls in js file for same jsp file.

```
//success
$("#searchButton").click(function() {
var searchString = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
$.post("../person/search", {        
    search : searchString
}, function(data, status) {
    makeTable(data, status);
});
})

//not found
$("#insertForm").submit(function(event) {
$.post("../person/insert", {        
    firstName : document.getElementById('firstName').value,
    lastName : document.getElementById('lastName').value,
    ...
}, function(data, status) {
    makeTable(data, status);
})
event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is my struts.xml:

```
<pakage name="person" namespace="/person" extends="myDefaultPakage">
<action name="insert" class="action.PersonAction" method="insert">
        <result >...
</action>
<action name="search" class="action.PersonAction" method="search">
        <result>...         
</action>
</pakage>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking here...

Comment: i mean: 2 post url are similar, but one get 404